# Use new libraries in java with old JDK

Tags: java, java-8, java-5

I have in my computer java 8, and I use all the new libraries in java 8, but I'm compiling it on JDk5 because my client has an old version of java and he don't want to change it.

I want to ask - How can I include the libraries that I use from java 8 so my program work in the client's computer?

Comment: If client runs java 5 then you can't execute java 8. If clients wants latest java to be used, he has to upgrade. If not, you must use java 5.

Comment: I don't **execute** java 8, I compile with JDK5, I just want **the libraries** of java 8

Comment: Java 5 cannot compile java 8.

Comment: If you mean that java 5 can't compile the libraries of JRE5 - that's not true. I tried to use stream(peek,map) an it's works. I just can't use lambda expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libraries of Java 8 *themselves* depend on new language features built into Java 8.  For example, they use lambdas and default methods and static methods on interfaces themselves.

This means that you cannot just run the libraries of Java 8 in the Java 5 runtime.  The libraries built into Java 8 themselves depend critically on the Java 8 runtime.

You cannot do this.

Comment: I think I got it. I tried to run with java 5 an I had this result - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/function/Co
nsumer
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)` and I think it is the reason

Comment: That just tells you that the library isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to generate classes with source compatibility of 1.5 using JDK 1.8.
This however, **will not allow you to use source files higher than Java 1.5**, and  existing constructs such as lambda expressions for instance, won't compile.
For this approach you need to perform the following:

1. Set *"Compiler"* options to non default and specify "Generated
   .class files compatibility" to 1.5.
2. Set *"Source
   compatibility"* to 1.5.

[image]
I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: why you are saying that? if I just change the compiler but don't change the "source compatibility" it still compiles with java 5 and **can** use the file higher than java 5, if it cna't be done - why it can compile?

Comment: Compiler settings can stay as 1.8, but class files are generated for java 1.5.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. so I can I change only the compiler and not the source?

Comment: @shmil, see the picture

Comment: What’s the point of this fancy setting? Setting the compiler compliance level to `1.x` is a short-hand for setting both, the `.class` file compatibility and the source compatibility to `1.x`. Thus, setting both to `1.5` manually does the same as setting the compiler compliance to `1.5` and leave the “default compliance” box checked. In your screenshot, the fact that the base setting is `1.8` has no effect at all.